# Aligning the elements In the same manner using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to web development.

**I have the following code**:

```css
.notation {
  width: 170%;
  margin-left: -238px;
}

.mytable {
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  width: 59%;
}

table.mytable>*>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

table.mytable {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  color: #222;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive notation" ng-if="(documentType !== 'jobDescription')">
  <table class="mytable" style="margin:0.5em auto; font-size:90%;position:relative;width:60%;margin-bottom:13px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#fce8e8;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Full Name</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#e2d6f1;text-align:center;"></td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:aqua;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Telephone Number</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#ccfcdd;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Total Experience</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:skyblue;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Skill Set</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable" style="margin:0.5em auto; font-size:90%;position:relative;width:60%;margin-bottom:13px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#d1cff7;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Company Experience</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#e8dca7;text-align:center;"></td>
        <td>Education</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#10eabe;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#aee8dc;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#f2d7da;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Address</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Now the output looks like**

[image]

But here, What is happening, this things are not getting aligned, I mean `FullName` is taking small space but the `companyExperience` is taking much space so, I want to have every element aligned.

So, How can I do this ?

**Updated-**

[image]

I am getting this type of output.

Comment: You should avoid using so much inline CSS.

Comment: @ganesh Use classes and give CSS styling to those classes!

Comment: And you should also avoid using tables for layout - although you may have tabular data, the way you use the table is not semantically correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the kind of output you want ?

```css
.notation {
  width: 170%;
  margin-left: -238px;
}

.mytable {
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  width: 59%;
}

table.mytable>*>tr>td {
  /*border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;*/
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

table.mytable {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  color: #222;
  margin: 1em 0;
  /*border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;*/
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive notation" ng-if="(documentType !== 'jobDescription')">
  <table class="mytable" style="margin:0.5em auto; font-size:90%;position:relative;width:60%;margin-bottom:13px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#fce8e8;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Full Name</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#e2d6f1;text-align:center;"></td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:aqua;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Telephone Number</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#ccfcdd;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Total Experience</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:skyblue;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Skill Set</td>
      </tr>
    <!--/tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable" style="margin:0.5em auto; font-size:90%;position:relative;width:60%;margin-bottom:13px;">
    <tbody-->
      <tr>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#d1cff7;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Company Experience</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#e8dca7;text-align:center;"></td>
        <td>Education</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#10eabe;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#aee8dc;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td style="width:2.5em; background-color:#f2d7da;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Address</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I only changed some of your code as comments. (Check it above)
You didn't need to use two `table`s, only two `tr`s.

Comment: Its removing the borders related to that boxes

Comment: Its actually removing all the borders that are there for all annotations.

Comment: @ganesh, By "borders", do you mean the "empty" space you got in your image between the two tables?

Comment: No It means the lines which are seperating the tds.

Comment: @ganesh if you run the example above, there are lines between the tds. Did you do something different to what's in the answer?

Comment: Actually, I have edited question there I have added a image.Please check that, This is the output which I am getting after using this.

Comment: Thanks , I got this.

Comment: @ganesh Do you prefer like that ? I've commented some on the CSS code.

Comment: No, You did this. Thanks,It was my bad , Using different class Name so it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.notation {
  width: 170%;
  margin-left: -238px;
}

.mytable {
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  width: 59%;
}

table.mytable>*>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

table.mytable {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  color: #222;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.mytable td{
  width: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive notation" ng-if="(documentType !== 'jobDescription')">
  <table class="mytable" style="margin:0.5em auto; font-size:90%;position:relative;width:60%;margin-bottom:13px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#fce8e8;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Full Name</td>
        <td style="background-color:#e2d6f1;text-align:center;"></td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td style="background-color:aqua;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Telephone Number</td>
        <td style="background-color:#ccfcdd;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Total Experience</td>
        <td style="background-color:skyblue;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Skill Set</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable" style="margin:0.5em auto; font-size:90%;position:relative;width:60%;margin-bottom:13px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#d1cff7;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Company Experience</td>
        <td style="background-color:#e8dca7;text-align:center;"></td>
        <td>Education</td>
        <td style="background-color:#10eabe;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td style="background-color:#aee8dc;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td style="background-color:#f2d7da;text-align:center;"><b></b></td>
        <td>Address</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you want them as two seperate tables